# TFS Check-In Note customization

Tags: tfs

I added a "Code Reviewer" as **required** checkin notes field. But it is in the form free text field. Instead of free text i want a user drop down. and select should be able to select from that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TFS 2010 supports only text checkin notes. In TFS 2012 there will be native support for code reviews, however I don't believe it's done through checkin notes. You can try useing checkin policies to validate checkin note value (not very user friendly though).

Comment: Thanks. Using checkin policies i am able to validate. But can i change the value of the checkin note and get reflected in the UI?  ex., PendingCheckin.CheckinNotes.CheckinNotes.Values[0].Value = "ABC";

Answer (score 0):

If you're only reviewing whole workitems (just before they go from Active to Resolved for example), not just checkins, then you can add a new work item field and that will show a user dropdown. You can make this field required to transition from Active to Resolved (mind the reason here!), and thus have a proper validation. Your user will have to update the workitem and you will have to associate the workitem to the checkin for this trick to work though.

And as MichalMa said, this will all change in Dev11.